# How to change side menu background color in ionic 4?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to change the side menu background color, I tried a few things but not working.

```
ion-menu{
    ion-content{
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }

    .inner-scroll {
        --background: var(--ion-menu-background);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can change background color in ionic 4?.

Comment: even for `ion-content` you need use css variable to set background-color.

Comment: i tried this things, i just want change menu background color...

Comment: can you create stackblitz?

Answer (score 2):

In cases where there are  gradients and shades of colors, you can try this. This is particularly useful if you want the entire side-menu to have a gradient, without any borders, separating the toolbar, content and items.

// In variable.scss file you can create your Ionic css variables

```
:root
{
--custom-menu: radial-gradient(
        circle farthest-corner at 10% 20%,
        rgba(246, 133, 133, 1) 16.3%,
        rgba(172, 131, 241, 1) 90%
    );
}
```

// In the app.component.scss file you would need to reference the variable that you created

```
 ion-menu {
    --ion-background-color: var(--custom-menu);

    ion-toolbar {
        --background: transparent;
    }

    ion-list {
        background: transparent;
    }
    ion-item {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        --background: transparent;
    }
    ion-content {
        --background: transparent;
    }
}
```

// In the appcomponent.html file, ensure that you specify the no-border directive

```
<ion-header no-border>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Test</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubNj7.png)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
    .inner-scroll {
        background: green;
    }
   .inner-scroll .item-native{
        background: green;
    }
```